# Add authentication to Bot V4 does not prompt for user login

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, botframework

I have been following the directions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp to add authentication to my bot (x).  So far, I have done the following:

1. Created AD V1 application
2. Created AD V2 application
3. Successfully configured OAuth Connection Settings called "XAuth" to my bot (x) and used AD V1 (AppId, AppPassword).  The test connection returns positive response.
4. Configured the sample bot application at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication, changed the connectionName to XAuth, added AppId and AppPassword from my bot (x)
5. Published bot application to Azure https://X.azurewebsites.net/
6. Configured Emulator for both development and production
7. Both Development and production are responding to help, logout commands in the emulator without prompting for signin dialog.

Since the sample project entrance has calls to WaterfallDialog(authDialog), I am expecting an automatic prompt. However, both environments do not prompt for user login.  The .bot file has configuration for both production and development with appId and password.  I couple of questions to understand the scenario better.

1. What do I need to do to get the prompt in Emulator?
2. What is the expected behavior in production?  Am I supposed to get prompted when I test my bot (x)?
3. what happens if I have more than one OAuth configuration in my bot (x)?  Which one will be in effect?  How do I control that behavior?

Comment: For 1) Did you try entering any text? it should show a sign-in card

Answer (score 0):

Was faced with the problem specified at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4632